# Is there a way to count the number of Changes that occur in a column and create a new count column based on that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns, and I want to add another column that counts the number of times a change occurred on the first column based on the ID of the second column.

Here is an example:

```
Date      User ID  
01.05.20   CT500
01.05.20   FC200
01.05.20   FC200
02.05.20   TH600
02.05.20   OR100
04.05.20   UI800
05.05.20   UI800
06.05.20   UI800
09.05.20   UI800
```

And I want the output to be like so:

```
Date      User ID  No.of Changes
01.05.20   CT500         1
01.05.20   FC200         1
02.05.20   FC200         2
02.05.20   TH600         1
02.05.20   OR100         1
04.05.20   UI800         1
05.05.20   UI800         2
06.05.20   UI800         3
09.05.20   UI800         4
```

So that every time that the User ID stays the same but the Date changes, I want it to add +1count to the last column. If the User ID stays the same and the Date stays the same, then the number should stay the same. So it essentially counting the times that the date changed (based on the product ID) into a new column.

I tried to use:

`df['No.of changes'] = df.groupby(['Date','Product ID']).cumcount()+1`

However, this started counting the number of times the same date occurred with the same product ID. Is there a way to count the times the date value changed into a new column?

Comment: In your question, you've got the date for the two `FC200` rows as `01.05.20` but in the expected output, it's `01.05.20` and `02.05.20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data are ordered by *Date* and *User ID* (else sort them with `sort_values`):

```
>>> df
        Date User ID
0   01.05.20   CT500
1   01.05.20   FC200
2   01.05.20   FC200  # dup.
3   01.05.20   FC200  # dup.
4   02.05.20   FC200
5   02.05.20   OR100
6   02.05.20   TH600
7   04.05.20   UI800
8   05.05.20   UI800
9   06.05.20   UI800
10  09.05.20   UI800
```

Then drop duplicated values before counting and finally fill missing values with last valid observation (because your data are sorted!):

```
>>> df.assign(Changes=df.drop_duplicates(["Date", "User ID"]) \
        .groupby(["User ID"]).cumcount()+1).ffill()
        Date User ID  Changes
0   01.05.20   CT500      1.0
1   01.05.20   FC200      1.0
2   01.05.20   FC200      1.0  # no inc.
3   01.05.20   FC200      1.0  # no inc.
4   02.05.20   FC200      2.0
5   02.05.20   OR100      1.0
6   02.05.20   TH600      1.0
7   04.05.20   UI800      1.0
8   05.05.20   UI800      2.0
9   06.05.20   UI800      3.0
10  09.05.20   UI800      4.0
```

**Edit**: add a third column *Type*

The solution is the same than the previous one: remove duplicated values.

```
>>> df2
        Date User ID Type
0   01.05.20   CT500   CT
1   01.05.20   FC200   FC
2   01.05.20   FC200   FC
3   01.05.20   FC200   XX  # diff. type, same date
4   02.05.20   FC200   FC
5   02.05.20   OR100   OR
6   02.05.20   TH600   TH
7   04.05.20   UI800   UI
8   05.05.20   UI800   UI
9   06.05.20   UI800   UI
10  09.05.20   UI800   UI
```

```
>>> df2.assign(Changes=df2.drop_duplicates(["Date", "User ID", "Type"]) \
         .groupby(["User ID"]).cumcount()+1).ffill()
        Date User ID Type  Changes
0   01.05.20   CT500   CT      1.0
1   01.05.20   FC200   FC      1.0
2   01.05.20   FC200   FC      1.0
3   01.05.20   FC200   XX      2.0  # inc. here because type is diff.
4   02.05.20   FC200   FC      3.0
5   02.05.20   OR100   OR      1.0
6   02.05.20   TH600   TH      1.0
7   04.05.20   UI800   UI      1.0
8   05.05.20   UI800   UI      2.0
9   06.05.20   UI800   UI      3.0
10  09.05.20   UI800   UI      4.0
```